# Http Post data from Python to net core app

Tags: python, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to send a file from a Python script to my .net core webserver.

In Python I am doing this using the `requests` library, and my code looks like so.

```
    filePath = "run-1.csv"
    with open(filePath, "rb") as postFile:
                file_dict = {filePath: postFile}
                response = requests.post(server_path + "/batchUpload/create", files=file_dict, verify=validate_sql)
    print (response.text)
```

This code executes fine, and I can see the request fine in my webserver code which looks like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]
    public string Create(IFormFile file) //Dictionary<string, IFormFile>
    {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                file.CopyTo(ms);
                var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                Debug.Print(text);
                return "s";
    }
```

However, the file parameter always returns as null.
Also, I can see the file parameter fine when getting data posted from postMan
[image]
I suspect that this problem has to do with how .net core model binding works, but not sure...
Any suggestions here on how to get my file displaying on the server?

Comment: I think your issue here, is from python you are first addressing to files it should be file, and secondly, are you sure that you are only sending one file, and is that the correct way to send a file?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my issue - the problem was that in Python I was assigning my file to my upload dictionary with the actual file name "./run1.csv" rather than a literal string "file"
Updating this fixed my issue.

```
file_dict = {"file": postFile}
```

This is what I believe @nalnpir mentioned above.
I figured this out by posting from postman and also from my python code to http://httpbin.org/post and comparing the respoinse

Answer (score 0):

The example from the requests docs is mostly correct, except that the key has to match the parameter of the controller method signature.

```
url = 'https://www.url.com/api/post'
files = {'parameterName': open('filename.extension', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

So in this case the controller action should be

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post(IFormFile parameterName)
```